# PHP Word Replacing Issue

Tags: php

Actually this problem shouldn’t be that much hard but I searched for it in stackoverflow but couldn’t find anything that works as I want or I can understand. Here’s what i’m asking for:
Image there is a text like: 
“hi today the temperature is high”
I’d like to replace string “hi” with “al” but I don’t want the word high to be replaced to as “algh”. I know I need to use preg_replace function but i couldn’t make it work.

ps: If you can show your solution with an array too, I will be more satisfied. Like there’s an array of strings to be changed and there’s an array of strings to be changed as.

Appreciate your help thanks :)

Comment: This is straightforward and well documented in many places. Have you tried anything? Please read about [ask] questions here.

Comment: You are completely right about that satisfying thing. I’m kind of new in PHP. It’s not right to say new but i’m not familiar with complex systems. Just do the stuff I need. It was a bit hard for me to understand when I read about in this during my research. I tried to kindly ask if right answer could help me with this if we use an array instead of just a single string. But thanks for warning, I’ll watch my language.

Comment: `with an array` shouldn't make much of a difference, just iterate over the array and fix the bits. It sounds like word boundaries would work for you, possible with the `i` modifier if all versions should be replaced, or `\b[Hh]i\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with \b to make it work.

```
$string = 'hi today the temperature is high';
$pattern = '/\bhi\b/';
$replacement = 'al';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

> **\b** assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

https://regex101.com/r/WdQTMp/2

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a **[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** against the non-whitespace character `\S`.

This results in the simple regex `hi(?!\S)`:

```
<?php

$string = "hi today the temperature is high";
$string2 = preg_replace('/hi(?!\S)/', 'al', $string);
echo $string2; // "al today the temperature is high";
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/jliOu)**.

Note that this will only cover strings that **start** with `hi`. In order to exclude strings that have text before `hi` (like `sushi)`, you'll need a **negative lookbehind** as well:

```
<?php

$string = "I eat sushi - hi today the temperature is high";
$string2 = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)hi(?!\S)/', 'al', $string);
echo $string2; // "I eat sushi - al today the temperature is high";
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/Qokml)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Gotta love StackOverflow, where people down-vote correct answers because they feel the OP hasn't done enough research of their own.

Comment: Alternatively, it could be that your answer isn't correct. Hint: it isn't.

Comment: "*Image there is a text like: 'hi today the temperature is high' I’d like to replace string 'hi' with 'al' but I don’t want the word 'high' to be replaced to as 'algh'*". Could you please explain how my answer does not do that? I'm happy to adjust my answer, but I genuinely believe it answers the question. Is it because I didn't do it with an array?

Comment: Think of all of the cases on which this might fail. `Say hi!` and `I eat sushi a lot` are just two examples. OP is obviously trying to avoid replacing partial words, not just the particular letters `hi` at the start of a larger word. And if you don't agree that's obvious, then it's at least implied. Your answer contains no explanation of the shortcomings of this approach. It may solve the question as explicitly stated, but it does not solve the question OP is clearly trying to ask.

Comment: While I disagree that the OP's intention was both clear and obvious, I've updated my answer to cover constraints, and to also add a negative lookbehind for words that end in `hi`.

Answer (score -2):

```
For example: 

<?php 
    $arrFrom = array("1","2","3","B"); 
    $arrTo = array("A","B","C","D"); 
    $word = "ZBB2"; 
    echo str_replace($arrFrom, $arrTo, $word); 
?> 

I would expect as result: "ZDDB" 
However, this return: "ZDDD" 
(Because B = D according to our array) 

To make this work, use "strtr" instead: 

<?php 
    $arr = array("1" => "A","2" => "B","3" => "C","B" => "D"); 
    $word = "ZBB2"; 
    echo strtr($word,$arr); 
?> 

This returns: "ZDDB"
```

Comment: This is obviously not what OP is asking about, and would not work for OP's use case.

Comment: This wasn’t what I asked for but I’ll keep in mind to use it later. Thanks for answering